# How to cancel a TRESTRequest?

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, cancellation

I'm consuming REST services using [`TRESTRequest`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequest). 
Sometimes users complain about very slow repsonses, so they want to be able to cancel REST-Requests.

Unfortunately there is nothing similar to a [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) that I could pass to the methods [`TRESTRequest.Execute`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.Execute) or [`TRESTRequest.ExecuteAsync`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.ExecuteAsync) in order to cancel a request while it's running.

I learned I can use [`THTTPClient.OnReceiveData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient.OnReceiveData) when I want to abort data reception. But I can't find a way to access the request's internal HttpClient.

How can I cancel a running REST-Request?

Comment: Do it in a thread, which has a callback. If user cancels, simply ignore the callback.

Comment: That's what I do at the moment. The problem with this approach is that I still download all data in background only to throw it away when it's done. This is a huge problem when bandwidth is low and the response is huge.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend not using `TRESTRequest`. Instead, use for example `TIdHTTP` and obtain the data in chunks.

Comment: `HTTPClient` is a private property of the `TRESTClient` (that you read by `MyRESTRequest.Client`). But you must publish it to access (e.g. by a class helper).